# problem of umbilic points

Tags: differential-geometry

[definition of umbilic in my notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvyhc.png)

My notes of geometry says that definition of **umbilics: k(u) is constant**, but when I search at google, I found out that many definition says that definition of **umblilics: principal curvature k1 and k2 have the same direction**.
Why are they the same? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you have a good feedback, I suggest that you would elaborate your question.

Comment: Thanks. hmmmmm as far as I know, the normal curvature k(u) = s(u)‧u , and principal curvature is maximum and minimum of k(u).
then why k(u) is constant means that maximum and minimum of k(u) have the same direction?

Comment: To me, it seems that it may talk "all direction is pricipal direction"

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. An umbilic point is one where both principal curvatures are equal, so that the normal curvature in *all* directions is the same.

Comment: I have just uploaded the definition

Comment: Your google results seem peculiar (not least because $k_1$ and $k_2$ are numbers, so have no direction). Are you sure you are reading them right? Any example links?

Comment: sorry for late reply. 
http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/CurveSuperfici/AG19.pdf
p.597

Answer (score 0):

Hint: IF $dN=\lambda(p) I$ just put for a parametrization  $X$ the following
$N_u=\lambda X_u$ occurs so deriving with respect to $v$ we have
$$N_{uv}=\lambda_v X_u+\lambda X_{uv}$$ exchanging $u$ and $v$ we get
$$N_{vu}=\lambda_u X_v+\lambda X_{vu}$$

using Schwarz we get

$$\lambda_v X_u=\lambda_u X_v$$

Since $X_u$ and $X_v$ linearly Independent we obtain
$\lambda_u=\lambda_v=0$.